# UILocalizedIndexedCollation in this use case

Tags: swift, tableview

How to add **section headers** and **index list** to `UITableView` in **this use case**?

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

var detail: Detail? = nil
var list = [tabledata]()
let search = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    list = [

        tabledata(name:"something".localized, sort:"sort.something".localized, id:"something.html"),
        tabledata(name:"somethingelse".localized, sort:"sort.somethingelse".localized, id:"somethingelse.html"),
        ...

    ]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "library", for: indexPath)
    var data: tabledata
    data = list[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = data.name
    return cell

}
```

**Now the point is that table data are going to be translated.**

Note that

- `name:` is the actual cell name going to be **`.localized`**
- `sort:` has to help characters like `á` `é` etc. in cell name to sort properly (avoiding them to show in the end of alphabet)
- `id:` calls the html file location to display in `detailViewController` ('cause name has to be translated and we want a static text here)

**A usual implementation of section headers and index list** will result in something like

```
T                 // section header
translation       // cell names
transmission
...

T                 // table in
Übersetzung       // another language
Getriebe
...
```

> **What's the correct model for UILocalizedIndexedCollation?**

---

**[.xcodeproj](http://github.com/pancoq/core)** on my github. More info on demand.

Thanks for help!

Comment: @matt I've got it running **based on your tutorial** with my tabledata list. but I am not able to use search bar. when I use search bar, I can scroll to the next letter and than got crash. do you have time to help me with that? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:** it turns out that "getting the first letter of each row to use as the index" is much more complicated than I thought when accounting for multiple languages, especially non-Latin ones. I'm making use of `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` to simplify this task.

---

I think that `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` is more confusing than rolling your own data models. You need to 2 models: one to represent the row and one to represent the section:

```
// UILocalizedIndexedCollation uses a selector on the `name` property
// so we have to turn this data type in to a class.
class TableRow: NSObject {
    @objc var name: String
    var id: String
    var sectionTitle = ""

    init(name: String, id: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
    }
}

// TableSection does not have to be a class but we are making it so
// that it's consistent with `TableRow`
class TableSection: NSObject {
    var title: String
    var rows: [TableRow]

    init(title: String, rows: [TableRow]) {
        self.title = title
        self.rows = rows
    }
}
```

After that, populating and filtering the table is very easy:

```
class Library: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var detail: Detail? = nil
    var list = [TableSection]()
    var filter = [TableSection]()
    let search = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    let collation = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.current()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // search
        search.searchResultsUpdater = self as UISearchResultsUpdating
        search.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        search.searchBar.placeholder = "search".localized
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        navigationItem.searchController = search
        definesPresentationContext = true

        // Set the color of the index on the right of the table.
        // It's settable from Interface Builder as well
        tableView.sectionIndexColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 122.0 / 255.0, blue: 1, alpha: 1)

        // I took the liberty to add a few more items to the array
        let rows = ["something", "somethingelse", "apple", "orange", "apricot", "strawberry"].map {
            TableRow(name: $0.localized, id: $0)
        }
        list = organizeIntoSections(rows: rows)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // Organize rows into sections with titles
    func organizeIntoSections(rows: [TableRow]) -> [TableSection] {
        // Organize the rows into sections based on their `name` property
        let selector: Selector = #selector(getter: TableRow.name)

        // Sort the rows by `name`
        let sortedRows = collation.sortedArray(from: rows, collationStringSelector: selector) as! [TableRow]

        // Allocate rows into sections
        var sections = collation.sectionTitles.map { TableSection(title: $0, rows: []) }
        for row in sortedRows {
            let sectionNumber = collation.section(for: row, collationStringSelector: selector)
            sections[sectionNumber].rows.append(row)
        }

        // Remove empty sections
        sections.removeAll(where: { $0.rows.isEmpty })
        return sections
    }


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if let selection = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: selection, animated: animated)
        }
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    // MARK: - Table View
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return filtering() ? filter.count : list.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        // If a section has no row, don't show its header
        let data = filtering() ? filter[section] : list[section]
        return data.rows.isEmpty ? nil : data.title
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filtering() ? filter[section].rows.count : list[section].rows.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "library", for: indexPath)
        let data = filtering() ? filter[indexPath.section].rows[indexPath.row]
                               : list[indexPath.section].rows[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = data.name
        return cell
    }

    func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        return filtering() ? filter.map { $0.title } : list.map { $0.title }
    }

    // MARK: - Segues
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "transporter" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let selected = filtering() ? filter[indexPath.section].rows[indexPath.row]
                                           : list[indexPath.section].rows[indexPath.row]
                let controller = (segue.destination as! Detail)

                // This assumes you change `controller.result` to have type TableRow
                controller.result = selected
            }
        }
    }

    // search filter
    func filterContent(_ searchText: String) {
        let query = searchText.lowercased()

        filter = list.compactMap { section in
            let matchingRows = section.rows.filter { $0.name.lowercased().contains(query) }
            return matchingRows.isEmpty ? nil : TableSection(title: section.title, rows: matchingRows)
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchEmpty() -> Bool {
        return search.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
    }

    func filtering() -> Bool {
        return search.isActive && (!searchEmpty())
    }
}
```

#### Results:

English:

[image: English]

Italian:

[image: Italian]

Slovak:

[image: Slovak]

*(I got the translation from Google Translate so my apology in advance if any word is out of whack -- I cannot speak Italian or Slovak)*

Comment: can you make a pull request to my GitHub maybe? I've got Cannot assign value of type 'TableRow' to type 'ghost?' in controller.result = selected

Comment: so now everything is working (thanks!) except segue to the detail view controller (maybe I am missing something)

Comment: I did change `result` property of the detail controller to `TableRow`. Did you make the same change? Also, can you elaborate on “not working”

Comment: and is it hard to implement index list with this model?

Comment: Very easy indeed. You already have all the sections and their titles. Away from a computer right  now so can't type up an edit. Will look at it later

Comment: I miss only one function to properly show the list. If you can help me then, will be awesome :) thanks

Comment: only that now I've got Use of unresolved identifier 'collation' in let sortedRows = collation.sortedArray ... Am I missing something again? :)

Comment: My bad... missed adding that to the view controller class. `let collation = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.current()`

Comment: sorry I am too exhausting... **Now it works!** only that it shows the whole alphabet, is there a way to get only used letters (like in sections)?

Comment: I considered that option and thought you don't want it. If you do, edit the `organizeIntoSections` with an extra command just before the `return`: `sections.removeAll(where: { $0.rows.isEmpty })`

Comment: **Perfect answer.** I'm sorry I do not have more bounty, as it was definitely worth more...

Comment: Thanks. You gave a bounty so I have to make the answer worth it.